# Cancelling jobs without dataloss on DataFlow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to find a way gracefully end my jobs, so as not to lose any data, streaming from PubSub and writing to BigQuery.

A possible approach I can envision is to have the job stop pulling new data and then run until it has processed everything, but I don't know if/how this is possible to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears this feature was added in the latest release.

All you have to do now is select the [drain option](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/stopping-a-pipeline) when cancelling a job.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this would be difficult (if not impossible) to do on your own. We (Google Cloud Dataflow team) are aware of this need and are working on addressing it with a new feature in the coming months.